# Вывод на терминал русских символов

Tags: windows, perl

Команда

```
print "Что-нибудь по-русски\n";
```

выведет на терминал всякие каракули (под Windows 7).

Как поменять кодировку вывода, чтобы печатало по-русски?

Comment: \n внесите за кавычки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед выполнением скрипта скомандовать

```
chcp 1251
```

И по необходимости [поднастроить шрифт.](http://xpoint.ru/forums/programming/perl/nursery/thread/43275.xhtml)